# lim $\frac{10^n}{n!}$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $a_n = \frac{10^n}{n!}$

a) To what limit does $a_n$ converge?

For $n \geq 10$, we have $a_n \leq 1$ and it is monotonically decreasing so $a_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

b) Give an estimate of the difference between $a_n$ and the limit

This question bugs me since based on the question, the difference is just $|a_n - 0| = a_n$, so the difference is $a_n$ itself but sadly, this is not the answer. Can anyone elaborate on this?

c) From what value of $n$ onward is this difference less than $0.01$?

Of course, I need the answer from b) to get this.

Comment: Try to read [$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a^n}{n!}, a>1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2087172/understanding-the-solution-to-lim-n-to-infty-fracann-a1?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We already had $6^n/n!$ today.

Of course, after $n=10$ the sequence decreases, but after $n=20$
the sequence decreases by at least a half at each step: $a_{n+1}\le a_n/2$
for $n\ge20$. So it must go to zero pretty quickly, mustn't it?

Comment: This is just a random pick right? I mean, it just so happens that what you stated is true but it can be anything as long as it is an estimate? In other words, my choice of n, say $n \geq something$ as long as I can show an inequality for $a_n$.

Comment: ...and we had $\;4^n/n!\;$ yesterday. Apparently some school/college/university left these exercises as personal ones in series/limits/whatever, and each student got a slightly different limit to evaluate. This is weary...

Comment: @DonAntonio xD Isn't that like $50\%$ of the problems on this site sadly?

Answer (score 1):

Using [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
a_n &\approx& \dfrac{10^n}{\exp(n \ln n - n)} \\
&=& \dfrac{e^n \cdot 10^n}{n^n} \\
&=& \left(\dfrac{10e}{n}\right)^n
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sequence $\left\{a_n\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that $a_n=\frac {x^n}{n!}$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$

Then taking the ratio of the sequence's $(n+1)^{th}$ term to its $n^{th}$ term yields:

$$\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac {x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\cdot \frac {n!}{x^n}=\frac {x}{n+1}$$

Which clearly converges to $0$ as $n\to\infty$.

So, simply choose $x=10$

Given $n$ arbitrarily large, we clearly see:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} (\frac {10^n}{n!})=0$$